# Mysql Service stopped running in middle of operation

Tags: mysql, windows-services

My software runs on a client machine and connects to a mysql server (another windows 7 PC) in the network. The error on the Client said: 
Unable to connect to the specified MySQL hosts.

After checking the server, I found that the MySQL service on the server had stopped. So, I tried to force start the service on the server from 'services.msc', but it gave this error:

**Windows could not start the MySQL56 service on Local Computer.
Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.**

I tried restarting the machine in a hope that it would help. It didn't. I've tried searching a lot on the net, but I'm unable to repair this. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Log file. This is not the answer. Just a clue.

Comment: Yes. Gave me a hit that the database is corrupt. Thanks